# How to assign a named key to an indexed array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an indexed array of no fixed length. The array values have a tag in front of them.
I want to loop through the array and assign the tag from the value to the key, and then deleting the tagged string from the value.

**The array I have **

```
Array
(
    [0] => <tag_0>Lorem Ipsum

    [1] => <tag_1> dolor sit amet

    [2] => <tag_2>consectetur adipiscing

    [3] => <tag_3>elit, sed do

    [4] => <tag_4>eiusmod tempor incididunt

    [5] => <tag_5>ut labore et dolore

)
```

This is just an example with only 5 elements.. it could be 500 elements.

**This is what I want the array to look like**

```
Array
(
    [<tag_0>] => Lorem Ipsum

    [<tag_1>] =>  dolor sit amet

    [<tag_2>] => consectetur adipiscing

    [<tag_3>] => elit, sed do

    [<tag_4>] => eiusmod tempor incididunt

    [<tag_5>] => ut labore et dolore

)
```

**This is what I have tried so far**

```
  foreach( $buffer as $key => $value ) {

    //find the position of the last meta tag in the value
    $meta_end = strpos( $value, ">" ) + 1;


    //substr the value and get the full meta tag from position 0 to the meta end    
    $newKey = substr( $value, 0, $meta_end );


    //set the newKey to the original array key
    $buffer[ $newKey ] = $buffer[ $key ];

    replace the meta tag string with blank space in the value
    str_replace( $value, " ", $newKey );


}
```

The above code partially works. I am able to use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the meta tag values.

When it comes to assigning the meta tags to the array key, it only works for the last portion of the array.

For example, if my array is 500 elements long, it will only work for the last 50 elements. So i end up with  a partial indexed array and partial named array.

**This is what I end up with above code**

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => <tag_0>Lorem Ipsum

        [1] => <tag_1>dolor sit amet

        [2] => <tag_2>consectetur adipiscing

        [3] => <tag_3>elit, sed do

        [4] => <tag_4>eiusmod tempor incididunt

        [5] => <tag_5>ut labore et dolore

        [<tag_6>] => <tag_6>magna aliqua. 

        [<tag_7>] => <tag_7>Ut enim ad minim veniam

        [<tag_8>] => <tag_8> quis nostrud exercitation

        [<tag_9>] => <tag_9>ullamco laboris

        [<tag_10>] => <tag_10>nisi ut aliquip

    )
```

I haven't even tried figuring out the code where I replace the meta tag with a blank string inside the value yet as I cannot set the key correctly.

Anyone have any ideas where i am going wrong?

Comment: To resolve the issues you have with your code, the main thing to change would be to change the way you create the new item `$buffer[ $newKey ] = substr( $value, $meta_end);` and add `unset($buffer[$key]);` to the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to extract the key and value parts for the new entry, and then simply [`unset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the old value in the array:

```
foreach ($buffer as $key => $value) {
    preg_match('/^(<[^>]+>)(.*$)/', $value, $matches);
    $buffer[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
    unset($buffer[$key]);
}
print_r($buffer);
```

Output (for your initial sample data):

```
Array
(
    [<tag_0>] => Lorem Ipsum
    [<tag_1>] =>  dolor sit amet
    [<tag_2>] => consectetur adipiscing
    [<tag_3>] => elit, sed do
    [<tag_4>] => eiusmod tempor incididunt
    [<tag_5>] => ut labore et dolore
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/R203C)

Note that this code assumes there is no `>` in the tag names.

Comment: OP just has to think about if it is possible for the tag to have `>` in itself. If it doesn't this should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov agreed. I'm working on the assumption from the sample data that it doesn't. I've made a note in the answer to that effect.

Comment: Thanks for this, does what it needs to do. However, The issue still persists where it only applys this code to the last portion of the array. When i do a 'print_r' it only shows the an array with the modified version

Comment: It sounds like you might have some characters that are not what they look like. Have they possibly been html entity encoded? e.g. the string is actually `&lt;tag_0&gt:`? Or perhaps they are Unicode not Ascii?

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji have you made any further progress? I'd really like to be able to help you resolve this.

Comment: @Nick unfortunately not. The tags are hard coded so they just plain strings. My array is actually 565 elements long. When I run the code provided and do a print_r after it, it runs correctly. However, it only shows the last 31 elements.

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji is there any way you could set up a demo on 3v4l with your actual array?

Comment: @Nick I can do, however, it contains sensitive information which I would rather not post. Any way I can send it to you privately?

Comment: If the information is sensitive I'd prefer not to see it. Can you possibly encrypt the non-`<tag_n>` sections?

Comment: @Nick I figured out why It only showing the last portion of the array. The tags are hard coded and are constant. However, they are used multiple times for each section of different information. So when it loops over and sees the same tag again, it replaces any of the keys and the elements with the new information. I will update the and setup a demo to show what is happening.

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji of course! that makes perfect sense... So it seems you will need perhaps another level in your array, splitting the sets of tags up according to the section they came from.

Answer (score 0):

if the tag is always called 'tag_'
try simply to build a new array:

```
function new_array($old_array){
    $new_array = array();
    foreach($old_array as $i=>$value){
        $tag = '<tag_'.$i.'>';
        $pos = strpos($value, $tag);
        $new_array[$tag] = $pos!==false ? str_replace($tag, '', $value) : $value;
    }
    return $new_array;
}

$old_array = new_array($old_array);
```

print_r($old_array); - will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [<tag_0>] => Lorem Ipsum
    [<tag_1>] =>  dolor sit amet
    [<tag_2>] => consectetur adipiscing
    [<tag_3>] => elit, sed do
    [<tag_4>] => eiusmod tempor incididunt
    [<tag_5>] => ut labore et dolore
)
```